# Given two functions, find a threshold such that one is always bigger than the other

Tags: python, recursion, proof

I've implemented the following two functions in Python:

```
def c(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return 0
    elif m == 1 and n >= 0:
        return n**2+n+1
    elif m > 1 and n == 0:
        return c(m-1, 1)
    elif m > 1 and n > 0:
        return c(m-1, c(m, n-1))
```

```
def d(n):
    exp_num = n-1
    result = 2
    while exp_num != -1:
        result = result**2
        exp_num -= 1
    final_result = 2**result
    return final_result
```

Where the inputs `m` and `n` are both natural numbers. I'm asked to find an `x`, such that for all numbers `y >= x`, `c(y,y) > d(y)`.

Some inputs and outputs:

`c(1, 1) = 3`

`c(2, 2) = 183`

`d(1) = 16`

`d(2) = 65536`

`d(3) = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936`

As you can see `d` grows extremely faster than `c`. How can I approach this problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd be better off asking this on https://math.stackexchange.com (defining the functions mathematically of course) as this is pretty much a calculus question. Converting the methodology back to Python should be relatively easy

Comment: Do you have problems computing c(y, y) for y > 2?  Computing c(3, 3) runs out of stack space even with Memoization.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about theoretical computer science (or math), not programming.

Comment: @davis herring--it could be about programming to the extent that c(3, 3) can't be simply calculated without overrunning the recursion stack.  Not clear why, since it seems like there would be very few recursions to compute c(3, 3).

Comment: @Badr--have you been able to compute c(3, 3)?

Comment: @DarrylG No, I run out of stack too. I think c is a variation of the Péter-Ackermann function but I'm not positive.

Comment: @Badr--yes, it seems to be a variant of the [Péter-Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) So, c(3, 3) doesn't seem to be realistically computable considering there are over 19K digit in A(4, 2) (where A is the Péter-Ackermann function).  But, this may mean the answer to your question is x =3.

Comment: @badr--think I found a way of proving that x = 3, and a way to get a lower bound on the value that I will post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function c is a variant of [Ackermann–Péter function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).

It claims to fame is that it is not [Primitive Recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) which for purposes here means it quickly runs out of stack space in its computation as the numbers become very large.

The problem is to find min x, such that c(y, y) > d(y), for y >= x.

We believe this is c(3, 3) but it can't be computed. We did compute for 1 & 2:

d(1) = 16, d(2) = 65536, d(3) = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936

c(1) = 3, c(2, 2) = 183, c(3, 3) = ?

Because it's not primitively-recursive, c(3, 3) is difficult to compute (i.e. run out of stack space).  However, rather than an exact number, we can obtain a lower-bound by 
by limiting the recursions in the function definition.

This is done as follows.

```
# Will use Memoization which eliminates repeated calculations in recursive functions
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
        self.memo = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self.memo:
            self.memo[args] = self.fn(*args)
        return self.memo[args]

@Memoize
def c(m, n, cnt = 0, MAX_RECURSION = 20):
    " Refactor function c to have a max recursion depth "

    if cnt > MAX_RECURSION:
        return 0   # We know the return value is always >= 0, but normally
                   # much larger.  By quitting early and returning zero we are
                   # ensuring our final computation will be smaller than it would
                   # otherwise if we had not limited the recurison depth
                   #

    if m == 0:
        return 0
    elif m == 1 and n >= 0:
        return n**2+n+1
    elif m > 1 and n == 0:
        return c(m-1, 1, cnt+1)
    elif m > 1 and n > 0:
        return c(m-1, c(m, n-1, cnt+1), cnt+1)

def d(n):
    exp_num = n-1
    result = 2
    while exp_num != -1:
        result = result**2
        exp_num -= 1
    final_result = 2**result
    return final_result


value_d = d(3)
value_c = c(3, 3)

print('Number of digits in d(3) is {}'.format(len(str(value_d))))
#>>> Number of digits in d(3) is 78

print('Number of digits in c(3, 3) is {}'.format(len(str(value_c))))
#>>>Number of digits in c(3, 3) is 74176
```

Thus, we see that c(3, 3) has ~1K more digits than d(3).  It will be even more since we stopped the recursion early in computing c(3, 3).

Comment: @Badr--glad to help.